# Rest API return status code 201 even with a "internal error"

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, postman

When a do a POST request with no body data it should return a status code 400, but it's returning a status code 201 with an empty object.

This the code:

```
router.post('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
const transaction = new Transactions({
    name: req.body?.name,
    amount: req.body?.amount,
    type: req.body?.type,
})
try{
    const newTransaction = transaction.save();
    return res.status(201).json(newTransaction);
}catch (err){
    return res.status(400).json({message: err.message});
}
})
```

This is the postman request and the response:

[image: Postman request]

Comment: How do you know an error occurred?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Df2f6Rl
Like... we need body.name and stuff to register a new transaction, so I think when we send nothing, some kind error will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like mongodb and mongoose. `.save()` returns an promise and should be resolved. You can do it with async / await here. What you return as an response is an pending promise.

```
router.post("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const transaction = new Transactions({
    name: req.body?.name,
    amount: req.body?.amount,
    type: req.body?.type,
  });
  try {
    const newTransaction = await transaction.save();
    return res.status(201).json(newTransaction);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: It was that. Thanks man!